# Appium Android dialpad Test is not working on previous version

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a simple test using Appium and android emulator with 4.4 that works fine,

I was trying the same on real device using a previous android version (4.2.1)

> ```
>     //4.4
>     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.dialer");
>     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity"); // This is
> ```
>
> Launcher activity of your app (you can get it from apk info app)

here is the Appium error

```
error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity

info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
```

I think the activity has changed on newer versions, can someone help me to identify the package and activity for 4.2.1

Comment: Can't give you an answer, but I can give you a tip that will help you in the future, also. Use monitor.bat in  your ANDROID_HOME/tools folder and start up the app. Then use the console to filter lines that look like they're coming from com.android.dialer to find the activity.

Comment: @masiles try using App info application it will help to find package and activity.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest appium version 1.4.16.1 version, you can skip APP_PACKAGE,  APP_ACTIVITY capability setting. Appium will fetch it from APK file.

By the way  `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity");` this should be `MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY`. Not `MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE`

Comment: I tried your fix, but I got the following error
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device